# Find a jacobian matrix of a vector-valued multi-variable functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, jacobian

**Here's the problem:**[P](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhAYO.png)

Find the Jacobian matrix of the following vector-valued multi-variable functions.
$f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is defined by $f(x) = \mathbf{A}\boldsymbol{x} − \boldsymbol{b}\,$, where $\boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n\,$, $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}\,$, $\boldsymbol{b} \in \mathbb{R}^m$.

**What I Know**

I am lost here. I know how to calculate a Jacobian Matrix for a given function. But I don't know how to get start for a vector-valued multi-variable functions like this one. Should I start with converting the function to matrix form first or? I just need a tip to start with.
Thanks.

Comment: One thing to note is that the problem as stated in the book has a typo. We cannot subtract a vector $\boldsymbol{b}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ from a vector $\mathbf{A}\boldsymbol{x}$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$. I assume that $\boldsymbol{b}$ is intended to be in $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: Some problems in maths require having ingenious insights or knowing tricks. This is not one of them. You just need to read the definitions and go ahead and do it. Trust me, you may think you're lost and just need a little help to get started, but really all you need is getting your hands dirty and doing things even if you aren't sure yet whether you're on the right track. Your solution may look less elegant than what people here come up with, and it may even contain mistakes, but it's yours, and you'll learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

Writing out our matrix $\mathbf{A}$, our vector $\boldsymbol{v}$, and our vector $\boldsymbol{b}$:

$$\mathbf{A} = \begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{a}_1\\ \boldsymbol{a}_2\\ \vdots\\ \boldsymbol{a}_m \end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} &a_{12} &\cdots &a_{1n}\\
a_{21} &a_{22} &\cdots &a_{2n}\\
\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots\\
a_{m1} &a_{m2} &\cdots &a_{mn}\end{bmatrix}, \qquad\boldsymbol{x}=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\\ \vdots\\ x_n\end{bmatrix}, \qquad\boldsymbol{b} = \begin{bmatrix}b_1\\ b_2\\ \vdots\\ b_m\end{bmatrix}$$

Where each $\boldsymbol{a}_i = \begin{bmatrix} a_{i1} &a_{i2} &\cdots &a_{in}\end{bmatrix}$ is a $1 \times n$ matrix (it can be seen as an $n$-dimensional covector if you are familiar with those).

Thus,

$$\boldsymbol{f}(\boldsymbol{x}) = \mathbf{A}\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{b} = \begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{a}_1\boldsymbol{x} - b_1\\
\boldsymbol{a}_2\boldsymbol{x} - b_2\\
\vdots\\
\boldsymbol{a}_m\boldsymbol{x} - b_m\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}f_1(\boldsymbol{x})\\
f_2(\boldsymbol{x})\\
\vdots\\
f_m(\boldsymbol{x})
\end{bmatrix}$$

Where $\boldsymbol{a}_i\boldsymbol{x} = {\boldsymbol{a}_i}^\intercal\cdot\boldsymbol{x}\,$.

For any $f_i(\boldsymbol{x})$, we have

$$f_i(\boldsymbol{x}) = \left(\sum_{j=1}^n{a_{ij}x_j}\right) - b_i$$

Using this, can you work out the Jacobian matrix $\mathbf{J}_{\boldsymbol{f}}\,$?

Comment: Thanks! Let me try to work out the rest.